# Can WebResponse.GetResponseStream() return a null?

Tags: c#, .net

i know its a noob question, but just wanted to know whether `GetResponseStream()` can return null in any case?

Comment: According to resharper it can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911056/can-webresponse-getresponsestream-return-a-null

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it's sort of up to the concrete subclass - but I've never seen any subclass which does so, and it's not *documented* as a valid return value. I've never seen any code written to defensively check for this, and I wouldn't expect to. That's not to say such code doesn't exist, but I don't think it's necessary.

If there's no content in the response (but the response was successful) I'd expect any good implementation to return an empty stream.

Comment: where did you find that "null" is not documented as a valid return value? Can you give me the link please?

Comment: @iotaSingh: How can I give you a link? I've said it's *not documented*. I didn't say it's documented as not being a valid return value, I said it's not documented as being a valid return value. Those are *very* different statements.

Answer (score 5):

**No built-in type derived from `WebResponse`, in particular `HttpWebResponse`, can return null.** This superstitious belief has misled many developers. Don't check for null. Such code is dead code.

What would null even mean compared to returning an empty stream?! This does not make sense.

**Also, `GetResponse()` cannot return null.** Again, what is that supposed to mean?! The HTTP protocol does not support the notion of a "null response". If that ever happens due to a library bug it's not possible to handle that situation anyway. Any such check does not help.

It is possible to create classes derived from `WebResponse` that return an insane values such as `null`. No built-in class does that and it should be considered a bug to return `null`. Classes derived from `WebResponse` are very rare. I have never seen one.

Here's a good code pattern to use:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://example.org/");

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    var contents = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

It demonstrates how to succinctly and safely read the contents of an HTTP URL using `HttpWebRequest`.